# Angular 4 innerHTML property removing id attribute

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom

I'm loading some HTML content by updating `innerHTML` of an element(loading some content after an api call). Everything works except one thing, which removes  `id` attribute from the content loaded.

Component code:

```
 content: string;
 @ViewChild('div') divContainer: ElementRef;

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    // actually hee loading content using some api call
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.content = "<a href='#' id='cafeteria' class='cafeteria'>Cafeteria</a>";
      this.cd.detectChanges();  
      this.divContainer.nativeElement.querySelector('#cafeteria').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('clicked');
      });
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Template :

```
 <div #div [innerHTML]="content"></div>
```

While inspecting in Chrome console :

[image]

In the above code `this.divContaainer.nativeElement.querySelector('#cafeteria')` returns `null` since id is missing and when I replaced with calss selector its working.

The `id` attribute is missing and class attribute is there, is there any specific reason for that?

Comment: can you try it with `safeHtml` pipe with `.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml`

Comment: @AswinRamesh :  let me try

Comment: @AswinRamesh : it's worked after using `DomSanitizer`...

Comment: @AswinRamesh :  something like this `this.content = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml("<a href='#' id='cafeteria' class='cafeteria'>Cafeteria</a>");`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

try this http://plnkr.co/edit/JfG6qGdVEqbWxV6ax3BA?p=preview

use a `safeHtml` pipe with `.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml`

```
@Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml'})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform  {
  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(value) {
    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div #div [innerHTML]="content | safeHtml"></div>1`,
})
```

Comment: But how do I make sure that it still sanitizes the unsafe parts like <script> tags?

Answer (score 9):

If you are not using innerHtml at multiple places

**In your TS**

```
content = "<a href='#' id='cafeteria' class='cafeteria'>Cafeteria</a>";
newContent:any;

    constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) { 
        this.newContent = this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content)
    }
```

**In your Html**

```
<div #div [innerHTML]="newContent"></div>
```