# Angular strips out data attribute from innerHTML

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a string returned from an API endpoint as below:

```
If you died tomorrow, your wife <span class='person' data-relationship='Relationship.Wife' data-avatarid='1212'>Alice</span> will lose everything.
```

So to display this as HTML I'm using the innterHTML property:

```
<p *ngFor="let con1Died of consequences?.client1Died" [innerHTML]="con1Died"></p>
```

But this is outputted to the browser with the data attributes stripped out as:

```
<p _ngcontent-smy-c63="">If you died tomorrow, your wife <span class="person">Alice</span> will lose everything.</p>
```

How can I output this WITH the data attributes? Is there a way to this?

EDIT: So I tried the HTML sanitation technique from below but the CSS still isn't applied:

[image]

```
this.reportsService.getConsequences().subscribe(res => {
      // Load the consequences to angular
      this.consequences = res;
      this.client1Died = new Array();
      this.consequences.client1Died.forEach(element => {
        const safehtml = this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(element);
        this.client1Died.push(safehtml);
      });
      console.log(this.client1Died);
    });
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48556861/angular-4-innerhtml-property-removing-id-attribute

Comment: Sort of - so it outputs the html as I want it but the CSS isn't applied so clearly it's not being read as HTML

Comment: See the edit above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a pipe to sanitize the Html:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml'})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform  {
    constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}
    transform(value) {
        return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<div [innerHTML]="content | safeHtml"></div>`,
})
```

Comment: That did make a difference but didn't resolve the issue - see above

Comment: are you usin the data attribute for css selector ?

Comment: its completely working as i have tested, if you are selecting the data attribute with css, i think you should move the css to your global styles

Comment: I am yeah and the person class

Comment: When I declared my pipe properly - this resolved the issue