# Typescript: Replace string & append HTML tag with id attribute

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to replace the string with an HTML tag & having an id attribute.

Here is my code,
TS file:

```js
let content = "this is a car.";
content.replace(new RegExp('car'), match => {
    return `<span class="highlight-text" id="car"> + match +</span>`;
});
```

```html
<div [innerHTML]="content"></div>
```

In inspecting element it shows only class,

```
<div>
    <span class="highlight-text">car</span>
</div>
```

It doesn't add an ID attribute in the span tag why?

Comment: You need to sanitize the html: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48556861/angular-4-innerhtml-property-removing-id-attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id field is eliminated by Angular in the process of DOM sanitization. To add the id field in the innerHTML, you will have to explicitly tell Angular, that it's safe to parse this HTML content. You can implement it in the following way:

```
let oldContent = "this is a car.";
oldContent.replace(new RegExp('car'), match => {
    return `<span class="highlight-text" id="car"> + match +</span>`;
});
let content = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content)
```

where, sanitizer is an instance of DOMSanitizer, which should be injected in the constructor.

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace returns modified content.

```js
let content = "this is a car.";
content = content.replace(new RegExp('car'), match => {
    return `<span class="highlight-text" id="car">${match}</span>`;
});
console.log(content)
```